# Work with iphone camera

Tags: iphone

I am looking for anyone that can help create some source and a tutorial with me to answer how to create a  transparent  straight  line on iphone camera.

Please , If anyone knows of a tutorial already then pls reply me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a live preview of the camera overlays by I more or less transparent line, right ?
Two solution come to my mind:
Build one view that gets the camera input via AvFoundation framework and build another - transparent - view that holds whatever elements you want to display on top of that.

Another solution would be to build one OpenGL view, use the camera input as texture for a background rectangle filling the whole screen and then render your other content on top of that.

Comment: can you provide any link for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking tutorial for camera overlay you can visit [this](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821). It has source code attached too. So you will find easy with that. But pls don't just copy paste try to understand the code when you have time.

Comment: dear sir,do you have any idea how can we draw a transparent straight line in iphone camera?